# Filtro por parâmetro ou todos

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Faço uma consulta no banco usando linq.

Gostaria de filtrar a coluna ID_LEAD pelo valor do filtro "se houver" int?(filtro.codigo) ou filtrar por todo mundo.

segue o exemplo de como esta no banco a procedure

```
WHERE ---- @ID_LEAD ----
LE.ID_LEAD = ISNULL(@ID_LEAD,ID_LEAD)
```

Gostaria de fazer isso na minha consulta

```
var lead = (from l in this.DB.BGC_LEAD
                                  where l.ID_LEAD == ).ToList();
```

Comment: Você quer validar se o `codigo` é `null` ou se ele é zero? (Para trazer todos os registros).

Comment: Boa pergunta! Fiquei com essa dúvida também.

Comment: Quero saber se o filtro.codigo e´null, caso seja null ele não sera um filtro, caso contrario quero filtrar pelo valor dele;

Comment: @JuniorTorres É exatamente isso que fiz na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/198791/18246)

Comment: @jbueno ele retorna todos os resultados passando null mesmo os outros registros não sendo null na coluna ID_LEAD ?

Comment: Claro, é isso que a expressão diz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só verificar se existe um valor na variável que guarda o filtro e trabalhar numa expressão booleana.

**Exemplo**

Se ele for `nullable` e `null` representar a ausência de parâmetro (ou seja, retornar todos os registros):

```
var lead = (from l in this.DB.BGC_LEAD
            where filtro.codigo == null || l.ID_LEAD == filtro.codigo.Value)
            .ToList();
```

Se ele for um `int` normal e 0 representar a ausência de parâmetro:

```
var lead = (from l in this.DB.BGC_LEAD
            where filtro.codigo == 0 || l.ID_LEAD == filtro.codigo)
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Seria isto:

```
var leadId = 0;

if(parametro == 1)
 leadId = 1
else
 leadId = 2;

var lead = (from l in this.DB.BGC_LEAD
                                  where l.ID_LEAD ==leadId).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, em sua consulta SQL você deveria fazer assim:

```
WHERE LE.ID_LEAD = 0 OR ID_LEAD = @ID_LEAD
```

No LINQ da mesma forma:

```
//pId é seu parâmetro (não nulo)
var lead = (from l in this.DB.BGC_LEAD
            where l.ID_LEAD == pId || pId == 0).ToList();
```

Se for passado como parâmetro o valor zero, então será verdadeiro para todas as ocorrências, caso, passe alguma coisa, irá considerar apenas o ID_LEAD igual ao parâmetro.

Comment: Amigo, o filtro.Codigo vem da view, pode ser nulo sim. então caso ele venha null, não quero filtrar por ele, caso ele venha preenchido quero filtrar por ele